# How to Convert .mp3 to text file in c#

Tags: c#, text, mp3, naudio, speech

I have used Naudio to convert .mp3 to .wav file then by using System.Speech dll converted .wav file to text file. Is there any way to convert .mp3 directly to text file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using System.Speech to convert mp3 file to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895933/using-system-speech-to-convert-mp3-file-to-text)

Comment: There's a possible duplicate to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895933/using-system-speech-to-convert-mp3-file-to-text)

Comment: Hmm... It's not really a duplicate because the the question contents were modified to use .wav file instead of .mp3

Comment: @m.rogalski Then that is the answer, no it cannot be done :)

Comment: @Jaxi noone specified that it's impossible. I'm guessing that it is possible but nobody wants to make it because it's complicated.

Comment: The System.Speech only seems to support input as wave files, and therefore doing what they wants to do would include writing your own converter, which would most likely ending up being a big project, not really a type of answer that would be received by a SO question :)

Comment: You always have to first decode the MP3 compression math to get back the original uncompressed digital audio (in PCM format, same thing what's inside a WAV file) then you can work with sound (analyse it, effect it, draw it, etc). No sound in MP3 (just numbers) until decoded into PCM.